# Cast one pointer-to-member-function to another of same class

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, reinterpret-cast

Is it legal to cast a pointer-to-member-function to another pointer-to-member-function of the same class using `reinterpret_cast`? The following example works. But is it legal?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

class A
{
    public:
    void func_int(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
    void func_string(std::string const& x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<void(A::*)()> v;
    v.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void(A::*)()>(&A::func_int));
    v.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void(A::*)()>(&A::func_string));
    A a;
    (a.*reinterpret_cast<void(A::*)(int)>(v[0]))(5);
    (a.*reinterpret_cast<void(A::*)(std::string const&)>(v[1]))(std::string{"Test"});

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At [[expr.reinterpret.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#10) the C++ draft states:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `X` of type `T1`” can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type “pointer to member of `Y` of type `T2`” if `T1` and `T2` are both function types or both object types.<sup>72</sup> The null member pointer value ([[conv.mem]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.mem)) is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type. The result of this conversion is unspecified, except in the following cases:
>
> - converting a prvalue of type “pointer to member function” to a different pointer to member function type and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.
> - converting a prvalue of type “pointer to data member of `X` of type `T1`” to the type “pointer to data member of `Y` of type `T2`” (where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.

> 72) `T1` and `T2` may have different *cv*-qualifiers, subject to the overall restriction that a `reinterpret_cast` cannot cast away constness.

Since you are converting your "pointer to member function" to a different "pointer to member function" type and back, it yields the original value. This is both legal and well-defined behaviour. So your code should work properly.